# Keycloak 400 bad request when [state] is old

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot application protected by Keycloak (15.0.2).

Let's say that I have a browser with two tabs opened for the same user and that user is authenticated.

Now I logout in tab 1 and I get the Keycloak login form with the following Url:

> http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/AUTOTEST_PG/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=mcd-client&state=e01b8a88-6945-4c56-9ee1-46fb156d33be&login=true&scope=openid

Now I logout in tab 2 and I get the Keycloak login form with the following Url:

> http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/AUTOTEST_PG/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=mcd-client&state=b9607387-7a05-4226-8313-4c5c80a1b145&login=true&scope=openid

Next, I tried to login in tab 1 and I get a 400 Bad Request response.

Looking at the Spring Boot log I get the following:

```
14554520 2021-12-14 00:02:06,100 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-8] DEBUG sample.controller.filters.MyKeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter ?:? -  -  -  -  - attemptAuthentication
14554520 2021-12-14 00:02:06,100 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-8] DEBUG sample.security.RealmProvider ?:? -  -  -  -  - getRealmName - requestUri: https://10.161.54.36/sso/login?redirect_url=/sctools/&state=e01b8a88-6945-4c56-9ee1-46fb156d33be&session_state=4fe8d159-5ada-4522-a422-07c5a0ce9d15&code=c5dda8ef-0fd9-4323-9922-fa5c73b28f89.4fe8d159-5ada-4522-a422-07c5a0ce9d15.442a440e-6df0-40c7-b8cb-3a52123430a0
14554520 2021-12-14 00:02:06,100 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-8] WARN  org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator ?:? -  -  -  -  - state parameter invalid
14554520 2021-12-14 00:02:06,100 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-8] WARN  org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator ?:? -  -  -  -  - cookie: b9607387-7a05-4226-8313-4c5c80a1b145
14554520 2021-12-14 00:02:06,100 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-8] WARN  org.keycloak.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator ?:? -  -  -  -  - queryParam: e01b8a88-6945-4c56-9ee1-46fb156d33be
14554521 2021-12-14 00:02:06,101 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-8] DEBUG sample.controller.filters.MyKeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter ?:? -  -  -  -  - unsuccessfulAuthentication - committed: true
14554521 2021-12-14 00:02:06,101 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-8] DEBUG sample.security.MyKeycloakAuthenticationFailureHandler ?:? -  -  -  -  - onAuthenticationFailure org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakAuthenticationException: Invalid authorization header, see WWW-Authenticate header for details
14554521 2021-12-14 00:02:06,101 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-8] DEBUG sample.security.MyKeycloakAuthenticationFailureHandler ?:? -  -  -  -  - onAuthenticationFailure - response isCommitted - Status: 400
```

It seems that the cookie sent and the state value doesn't match and that is the reason why I get a bad request.

How can I login from any of the tabs without getting the Bad Request ?

Note: If I go to the tab2 and login, then I get a message telling me that the user is already login.

**UPDATE**

When doing the same operation on the Keycloak console, if the user logout from one tab the second tab is automatically logout and the Url doesn't get an state variable it gets a challenge variable, something like:

```
http://10.161.54.36:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=security-admin-console&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F10.161.54.36%3A8180%2Fauth%2Fadmin%2Fmaster%2Fconsole%2F%23%2Frealms&state=c3015df8-4c50-4454-be8d-0555f25e3bd0&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=acb2a07d-c4a3-4cd3-8a7a-e23580a97d14&code_challenge=2W6-09eeD_WEwtWct3a5MojpIQJMe-9brcOH-7fbT6A&code_challenge_method=S256
```

How is it done ?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I'm facing the same

Comment: No, I didn't. Posting on the Keycloak forums might bring you a solution